# TOpenDialog hangs the program (but not during debug)

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

- I am using Delphi 7.
- TOpenDialog.Execute hangs the program if launched from the standalone
  EXE.
- When the project is executed from Delphi 7 it does not hang.
- It does not matter what I add, even a blank project with a button
  that has OpenDialog1.Execute on it will cause the hang when clicked.
- This problem is recent. **Projects compiled before a while ago do not have the hang.**
- I used the same Windows installation (Windows 7 Ultimate 64bit) and
  the same Delphi 7 for years now.
- Projects compiled before a while ago do not have the hang.
- Projects from Delphi 7 that are complied in Delphi 10 will also cause the hang.
- **It does not happen in CLX applications**, whether in debug or standalone.

Here's an example of what seems to be causing the hang:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 OpenDialog1.Execute;
end;
```

Update:
Cause might be "InitialDir" being the Desktop. If it's set to c:\ for example, it won't happen.

Comment: Works fine here. What's different about your setup.

Comment: I don't think my setup would affect it since it WORKS FINE HERE in the IDE.

Comment: It works fine here for me. What is different between what I do and what you do? Hint: you need to try to provide a [mcve].

Comment: I do not know what to say, it seems that some of my projects compiled a month ago are not causing the hang. 
In the question, I mentioned that ANY "topendialog.execute" will cause it.

Comment: This is somewhat excruciating. [mcve]

Comment: The minimal, complete and verifiable example is "OpenDialog1.Execute" and nothing more. Not even a semi-colon.

Comment: Works fine here, as I said. What's different about your machine?

Comment: If it doesn't happen when running from the IDE (presumably using Run with debugging), you might need to make a copy of the unit(s) that TOpenDialog depends on, add some OutputDebugString calls within the execution path for Execute, and use DebugView (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview)  to see how far it goes.

Comment: @Dave Or just stick madExcept in and use madTraceProcess. It's important to use powerful debugging tools to make life easy.

Comment: I don't know about all that but when "InitialDir" property is set to other than Desktop, it won't happen.

Comment: So it was incorrect when you said *"The minimal, complete and verifiable example is "OpenDialog1.Execute" and nothing more. Not even a semi-colon."*?

Comment: What does your code look like that sets `.InitialDir` to the Desktop? You need to add these details to your question.

Comment: I don't need to set the InitialDir. I said that if I set the InitialDir it wouldn't hang, the minimal code is still "OpenDialog1.Execute". This was very excruciating.

Comment: You said in your comment, *when "InitialDir" property is set to other than Desktop* which does not mean the same thing that you most recently said. So the default value for `InitialDir` is the desktop and if you leave it at default, it hangs, but if you explicitly set it to the desktop, it works in that case?

Comment: I said the default is Desktop but if I set it to c:\ for example, it won't hang.

Comment: Just to make sure I wasn't overlooking it after several re-reads, I did a page text search on "default" and "desktop" on your question and the comments and nowhere did you say the "default" is Desktop. So you just need to make your question clear and include actual conditions. And you didn't answer my last question.

Comment: It's an update.

Comment: So you are saying that when you start a new project, drop an TopenDialog on it and a button, and in the button OnClick you write "OpenDialog1.Execute;" you get this error ?

Comment: Almost, I create a new project, I drop a TOpenDialog, I add "OpenDialog1.Execute;" to a button's OnClick, I run, everything is fine.
I execute the standalone EXE project from the Explorer for example, when I click the said button, the program hangs.

Comment: does your delphi 7 starts with administrator rights ? And your standalone EXE not ?

Comment: They both have admin's. Tried runas with the EXE. Nothing.

Comment: maybe some antivirus/firewall issue where you have exluded the delphi 7 bin directory, but not the directory where your exe is stored ?

Comment: I disabled everything and tried. Nothing. I find it curious.

Comment: I once had to use ComObj/CoInitialize to make the new-style file dialogs (Vista+) work.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to look at is Project -> Options -> Compiler Messages (are there any unchecked?) If so,  those are exceptions begin ignored by the IDE's built-in debugger. Check them, and run, then you might see what is causing the hang-up.

The only time I have been able to produce this is when I have a network share that is sluggish or not there... during the IDE debugger it timesout and keeps going, however, standalone it will eventually timeout, but, much longer.

(Most likely it is something in your Project -> Options screen). As I do strange things that most people never do :-) (sshfs for example will cause this).

Answer (score 0):

I once had this problem in some of my application if i wanted to access network shares. By including the compiler switch

```
{$SetPEOptFlags IMAGE_DLLCHARACTERISTICS_TERMINAL_SERVER_AWARE}
```

I could get rid of the problem. See also [this blogpost](http://forum.madshi.net/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=27257). But be aware, that this switch has some [restrictions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc834995%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

As [Microsoft mentions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/01cfys9z.aspx), "The /TSAWARE option is enabled by default for Windows 2000 and later, for Windows and console applications", meaning every .NET application has this switch turned on by default.